# Isometric Drawing Tool: Converting 2D information to 3D

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

I was drawing with the [NCTM Isometric Drawing Tool](https://www.nctm.org/Classroom-Resources/Illuminations/Interactives/Isometric-Drawing-Tool/), and produced the image seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2qbV.png). I also noticed that it is possible to view the isometric drawing in [2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edtJD.png), and was wondering if/how it is possible to generate the 3D-coordinates of the blocks by using the information given in 2D.

Answer (score 1):

Isometric projection, in this case, is the orthogonal projection on plane with equation $x+y+z=0$ (or any affine plane with equation $x+y+z=d$). Thus

A first answer is 'no' because  depth information (depth in the direction of view, i.e., in the $(1,1,1)$ direction) is lost ; in the example you give, one could interpret the upper corner of the highest cube as having coordinates $(0,-1,5)$ but they could as well be

$$(0,-1,5)+t(1,1,1)=(t,t-1,t+5)$$

for any real number $t$...

A second answer is 'yes' as long as we have the absolute coordinates $(a,b,c)$ of a certain reference point $R$. Indeed in this case, one can retrieve the absolute coordinates of any point $S$ by first creating a path from (the projection) of $R$ to (the projection of) $S$ and then, while following the path, add $(\pm 1,0,0), (0,\pm 1,0), (0,0,\pm 1) $ to the current coordinates as we are moving South-East, North-West, South-West, North-East, South or North direction resp.

Remarks :

1) all paths from $R$ to $S$ give the same final coordinates to $S$.

2) thinking to reference (affine) plane with equation $x+y+z=1$, one could work with **barycentric coordinates**. I can even imagine that this "Isometric Drawing Tool" has been programmed using sort of coordinates. I will try to re-create it in this way in the coming times...

Comment: I don’t understand how you can retrieve the scene coordinates of a projected point even if you have a known reference pair. If the projections of two distinct points $S$ and $S'$ coincide, then the procedure you describe will produce the same world coordinates for them.

Comment: If, we proceed by starting from a point whose three coordinates are known,  going south west means "$y \leftarrow y-1$; going south east means "$x \leftarrow x+1$; going north means "$z \leftarrow z+1$ ; therefore, we can proceed in a step by step process keeping information on the 3 coordinates.

Comment: I understand the algorithm. What I don’t understand is how it can produce different results for distinct points whose projections coincide.

Comment: It doesn't look a paradox to me : we have added an information that we couldn't, indeed, extract from the figure as it was given.

Comment: So, you’re following edges in the projected image? In that case, I think that you should note that this only works because you’re using information/making assumptions about the original scene, namely, that all of the visible edges are aligned with the coordinate axes. As written, it seems like a general-purpose method to recover the world coordinates of a point.

Comment: That's fully right.