# How to convert 2D isometric information to 3D

Tags: 3d, projection

Is it possible to calculate the vertices and edges needed in order to create a 3D model from a 2D isometric image?

Using an isometric grid, we can as far as I understand, simulate the z-depth. Is there enough information to create the rest of the model to 3D if we set certain constraints on the model, like being symmetric?

I created a drawing using an [online isometric tool](https://www.nctm.org/Classroom-Resources/Illuminations/Interactives/Isometric-Drawing-Tool/)

[image: Isometric image]
[image: 3D-model]
From the gif above, we can see that some planes are missing.

Here is a more complex isometric drawing I made that I would love to convert into 3D (at least fill in the missing planes, and have a symmetric model)
[image]

Here is a similar question: [Isometric Drawing Tool: Converting 2D information to 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3151817/isometric-drawing-tool-converting-2d-information-to-3d?newreg=8f2274aaf2ff4f16953e0ba376223c4b). The difference is that question linked to asks if it is possible to create a 3D model from a front-view of a 2D model, but it is not possible because depth is lost.

Comment: The “isometry” tag doesn’t refer to isometric projections, but to distance-preserving maps.

Comment: Generally speaking, the answer is “no” for the same reason as in the linked question: depth information in the projection direction is lost. That said, any information that you do have about the original scene, such as knowing that certain points are coplanar or that certain lines/planes are orthogonal, can help with the reconstruction.